# is it possible to create a textarea in php with the goal of save this textarea in a php variable?

Tags: php, database

i woud like to know if it's possible to create a textarea in php with the goal of save this textarea in a php variable
for explanation, i have a form in html
what i would like to do :
in a specifique area give to users the possibility of write a paragraph 
i would like to  save this paragraph in a php variable to apply on this variable a function

once this function is applied i post it in my database

for exemple it will look like something like this:
into the form on a browser
    Enter a paragraph => blablabla;

```
<?php 
 $paragraph= user's paragraph;


 function color_paragraph($paragraph)
 ?>
```

i tried something like this:

filesave.php:

```
 if ($_POST){

    $variable=$_POST['paragraphe'];
    color_paragraph($variable) ;
    }
```

form.html:

```
<form method="post" action="filesave.php">

     <label for="paragraph">entrez votre paragraphe : </label>
    <input type="text" name="paragraph" id="paragraph" >

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

result: my function apply on the paragraph but the problem is that the submit do not work and he send me to my page filesave.php
all my code is not here ,
(of course i  settled all i need to connect to a database, and i can submit the data from the form to my database ,but by adding this (action="filesave.php" )that do not work and send me to the filesave.php page )

Comment: Go enable proper PHP error reporting NOW, so that PHP has a chance to alert you to such mistakes itself!

Comment: @kerbholz this is not my real code it's an exemple to show you what is my problem .my real code works

Answer (score 0):

If you want not to open the filesave.php you have to send asynchronous request.I would use jquery+ajax instead of form, because form is synchronous request

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'filesave.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: {'paragraph': $('#paragraph').val()},
    success: function(result){
        alert(result)
    }
})
```

Comment: "_because form is synchronous request_" What's wrong with a synchronous request?

Comment: @kerbholz I think that it reprents the response directly to the browser, so you get redirected to the filesave.php, while if you use ajax it won't